# Convert from 4 digit Military time to Standard time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2016 and I'm trying to convert military time to standard time. The military time is a 4 digit integer and I'm trying to get the standard time format (00:00 am/pm).

I ran a simple `CASE` statement that made it standard but without ':' and 'am/pm'.

```
CASE
  WHEN  SA_BEGTIME between 0 and 1259 then SA_BEGTIME  
  WHEN SA_BEGTIME between 1300 and 2400 then  SA_BEGTIME - 1200

  ELSE ''

END as Time
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTvlC.png)

How do I convert it so that it is in the right format: '00:00 am/pm'

Thank you!

Comment: Are you wanting a string (`varchar`) representation of the time, or a native `datetime` or `time` value?

Comment: Please show examples of your military time.  What does 5 minutes after midnight look like?   5 or 0005?  Using integers to hold time is problematic, as you lose zero padding and they can contain invalid times (2500 sounds fun, but is not actually valid)

Comment: there are no zero padding

Comment: @datagod here is the top 20 results SA_BEGTIME
1120
1540
1535
1715
1130
1020
1120
900
1040
1500
1100
1200
1245
1400
1430
310
1510
1500
1130
1550

Comment: @user5582884, see my answer below.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored as an integer, and also assuming there is not invalid time stored (i.e. values above 2400 or below 0) you can use the following:

```
declare @TheTime int = 900
select right(convert(varchar(20),
         cast(stuff(right('0000' + convert(varchar(4),@TheTime),4),3,0,':')
        as datetime),100),7)
-------
 9:00AM
```

Sorry for the density of the solution.  This is what I did:

1. Convert @TheTime to varchar(4)
2. Add a string of zeros at the front
3. Take the rightmost 4 characters from this new string
4. Stuff a colon sign in the middle of this new string
5. Cast the string as datetime
6. Convert back to string using 100 as the style indicator to get AM/PM
7. Get the right most 7 characters of the string.

I am sure there are more elegant ways, but this one works for me quite well.

Comment: Great :) this worked. I'm new to Sql and still learning and used your code like so:

Comment: select SA_BEGTIME ,right(convert(varchar(20),
        cast(stuff(right('0000' + convert(varchar(4),SA_BEGTIME),4),3,0,':')
        as datetime),100),7) as test
into #test
from [dbo].[vSALs]
where [SA_SRVDATE_YYYYMM] = '201510'

select * from #test

drop table #test

Comment: Glad to be of help.  If this is the solution you are happy with, please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can split it into parts with integer division and modulo, cast it to a VARCHAR and then you can convert it to a TIME:

```
declare @x int = 109

select cast(cast(@x / 100 as varchar(2)) + ':' + cast(@x % 100 as varchar(2)) as time)
```

Or you can use the new [TIMEFROMPARTS()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213398.aspx) function (SQL Server 2012+):

```
declare @x int = 109

select TIMEFROMPARTS(@x / 100,@x % 100, 0, 0, 0)
```

You can then format it however you'd like.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan No, but he says his input is an integer that represents military time, and integers don't get leading zeroes.  `109` is equivalent to `01:09` and `3` would be equivalent to `00:03`.  At least, that's the most logical way to me to store military time as an integer.

Comment: But he also say that he need to convert `Military time`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan He needs to convert military time *stored as an integer*.  The thousands and hundreds place represents the hours, and the tens and ones place represent the minutes.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, he also shows samples of his data stored as an integer.  900 is not military style, but it is how his system stores the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the solution that @BaconBits provided but I had to make a tweak because `2400` was a valid representation but it failed with that code. Here's the tweaked solution:

```
declare @x int = 2400
select TIMEFROMPARTS((@x / 100) % 24,@x % 100, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to convert a `datetime` field where the time was military to just the time in AM/PM format. This worked beautifully.

```
Left(convert(varchar(20), cast(MyDateField as time),100),7)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use convert to get n appropriate presentation of time.

```
declare @mt varchar(4) = '1500'

select convert(varchar, cast(left(@mt, 2) + ':' + right(@mt, 2) as time), 0)
```

Comment: If the source time is stored as an integer, your code will not work for times less than 1000.

Comment: @datagod Why it shouldn't work? Can you show me an example?

Comment: The source data in the original example is integer.  00:05 am is actually stored as 5.   Change your @mt to int and see what happens when you deal with integers that are less than 4 digits.

Comment: @datagod Give me a **4** digit integer less than 1000 and I will convert it for you :)

Comment: I don't think you understand, perhaps I am not explaining it properly.  In your example you have @mt varchar(4).  Change that to int.  Then use a time of 5 minutes after midnight.  This will become integer value 5.  Your conversion formula will not work properly.

Comment: @datagod, but I agree that you don't understand. Search for `Military Time Format`

Comment: His data is stored as an integer.  How would you convert the value 900?  Look at the actual data he posted.  Your method does not work. You do not have code to zero pad in your example.  It is you who does not understand.